# need a better way to validate fields in request body django depending on a specific field value

Tags: django, django-models, design-patterns, django-rest-framework, api-design

The requirement is to verify body fields in an api request depending on another field.

Like:
the request data has a field:

```
action
```

If actions is `deactivate`
then no other field should be present in the body data however if the action is anything else we want to allow updating other fields as well such as `name`.

currently we have a validation where we are going through the dictionary keys
and comparing like below:

```
expected_keys = ['client_updated', 'updated_by', 'actions']
```

```
if key not in expected_keys:
    raise ValidationError("Deactivation action does not allow {} to be updated".format(key))
```

Just wanted to know if there is a better way to handle via django or django rest framework, with somewhat less harcoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a JSON Schema to define your behavior and then validate the input against that schema when the request is sent. If acceptable, return 2xx response code and perform the action, otherwise, 400 response code and return the error encountered in the validation.

here's a sample of a conditional validation using `If, then`.  This will only work with JSON Schema draft-07 or later.

The jist is you can check the `const` (constant) value of a property and validate if it matches your condition, if it does, you can set the properties of `action` with `additionalProperties: false` because your condition stipulates if `actions=deactivate` then no other properties are allowed. It's a little verbose because you need to redefine the `properties` again inside the `then` but it gets the job done. The `if` condition will only evaluate to `true` when `actions=deactivate`, otherwise, the schema definition remains the same as originally defined prior to the `if`.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "actions": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "client_updated": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "updated_by": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "actions": {
                "const": "deactivate"
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "properties": {
            "actions": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/python-jsonschema/jsonschema is a great library to support this capability in your django project